# What is the idiomatic way to access an error's attribute in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript treats errors as `unknown` which is fair but leads me to writing what I think is ugly code. For example, to handle a particular error that I know has a `"code"` attribute (but I don't know the class so can't use `instanceOf`), I have to write this:

```js
} catch (err) {
    if (
      typeof err === "object" &&
      err !== null &&
      "code" in err &&
      (err as { code: unknown }).code === "<some value>"
    ) {
      console.log("Special case for this particular situation")
    }
    throw err;
}
```

I find this ugly, too much code, and I still have to do a cast. It's tempting now to cast `err` to `any` instead but I wanna do proper TypeScript.

What's a nicer way to do this?

Comment: Side note: TypeScript doesn't have *casting*, it has [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). There *is* a difference. :-) In languages with casting, a cast can actually modify the value you're casting (example from Java: `double d = 42.2; int i = (int)d; System.out.println(i); /* 42 */` -- the bit pattern was actually adjusted by the cast, converting the IEEE-754 double to a two's complement int.) TS's type assertions don't do that. They're **purely** you the programmer telling TypeScript "I know this is the right type for this."

Answer (score 2):

I've usually done what [Clashsoft showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74314631/157247). Just type `err` as `any` and then have a couple of guards.

But if you're doing that in a lot of places, it may be useful to have a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) you can reuse:

```typescript
function isErrorWithCode(err: any): err is { code: string; } {
    return err && typeof err === "object" && "code" in err && typeof err.code === "string";
}
```

Then usage is:

```typescript
try {
    // ...
} catch (err) {
    if (isErrorWithCode(err) && err.code === "<some value>") {
        console.log("Special case for this particular situation")
    }
    throw err;
}
```

If you really wanted to make it convenient, you could combine the type predicate with a function that checks for the given error code:

```typescript
function errorHasCode(err: any, code: string) {
    return isErrorWithCode(err) && err.code === code;
}
```

then:

```typescript
try {
    // ...
} catch (err) {
    if (errorHasCode(err, "<some value>")) {
        console.log("Special case for this particular situation")
    }
    throw err;
}
```

I have that in my Excel JavaScript add-in codebase for convenience. (The Excel JavaScript API sometimes throws errors with `code` property that's a string.)

Comment: Good approach, one small addition: your `isErrorWithCode` does not check that `err.code` is a `string`, yet it asserts that in the return type.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I would do, but this way: https://tsplay.dev/mZX9Ew

Comment: @Clashsoft - Thanks!! I missed that out. Fixed now. :-)

Comment: @jsejcksn - Ah, yes, more flexible that way. In my case I was always dealing with strings, but still...

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the `code`, I would go with this:

```
} catch (err: any) {
  if (err?.code === 'whatever') {
    console.log("Special case for this particular situation")
  }
  throw err;
}
```

If `err` is `null`, the optional chain expression will yield `undefined`, which is probably not your `whatever`.
Same result if `err` does not have a `code` property.

Comment: *"If err is `null`, the optional chain expression will yield `null`"* It will result in `undefined`, not `null`. And yeah, I was writing this same answer, with the caveat that I couldn't claim it was "idiomatic", but given you can only use `any` or `unknown` as the type of an error binding and the OP is looking for a specific value, it seems a perfectly reasonable approach.

Comment: Thanks, I edited that. Not sure where I got that from...

Comment: It was the other possible way they could have gone. :-) I'm just glad they didn't go with both (`null?.whatever` => `null`, `undefined?.whatever` => `undefined`). **That** would have been awful.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform your error in a class, throw it and then check for the error with `instanceof`

```
try {
  throw new MyError({ code: "Hello, world" });
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof MyError) {
    console.log(e.code);
  }
}
```

Otherwise you could use some libs like [Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) to validate it but introducing Zod just for this could be a little overkill.

Comment: The OP said *"I don't know the class so can't use instanceOf"*.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a case of either:

1. Knowing the type of the error in advance (in which case you can safely construct an interface/type to reflect that, if one is not available, and type-cast with `as` to guarantee future type safety within the block)
2. You don't know the type, but you know the property(s) you're interested in, in which case a solution like yours is somewhat necessary as you're trying to get from any possible type (e.g. `any` / `unknown`) to a specific subtype that the TS compiler will understand and be able to adhere to within block

A halfway house solution could be to define a type with the information you do know and omit the rest, e.g.

```
interface SpecificError {
  code: string,
  // ...
}

} catch (err) {
  const eTyped: SpecificError = e as SpecificError 

  eTyped.code // valid
}
```

or

```
} catch (err) {
  const eTyped: { code: string } = e as { code: string }

  eTyped.code // valid  
}
```

A slightly shorter way of implementing option 2 given the lack of information available to implement option 1.

Edit: @t-j-crowder's solution using type-guards is also an elegant way to achieve the same idea. Leaving this answer up in case the "quick but dirty" approach is also of value